# D-Bus questions: queue size?

Tags: dbus

I need help from experts in D-Bus. Cannot find the answer in D-Bus's documentation, but would be glad if someone points to a relevant chapter(s).

My environment: A Central app, which can be bombarded by requests from multiple sources.

The question are: If the Central is too slow to read messages sent to it - how long is the message queue? Where is it defined and modified?
What if the Central app left some messages unprocessed and the whole machine goes down - will the unprocessed messages survive? Or is the queue completely in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question are: If the Central is too slow to read messages sent to it - how long is the message queue? Where is it defined and modified?

The queue is managed by the bus daemon (of which there are two implementations; most Linux distributions use `dbus-daemon`, but it may be replaced by `dbus-broker` on some distributions).

In dbus-daemon, its limit is set in terms of *bytes,* not messages. See `man dbus-daemon`, search for "max_outgoing_bytes". The default configuration is at `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf` for the shared "system" bus (and similarly `session.conf` for the per-user "session" or "user" bus instances), with your custom configuration to be placed in `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/*.conf`.

(dbus-broker has different configuration.)

```xml
<busconfig>
  [...]
  <!-- The defaults for these limits are hard-coded in dbus-daemon.
       Some clarifications:
       Times are in milliseconds (ms); 1000ms = 1 second
       133169152 bytes = 127 MiB
       33554432 bytes = 32 MiB
       150000ms = 2.5 minutes -->
  <!-- <limit name="max_incoming_bytes">133169152</limit> -->
  <!-- <limit name="max_incoming_unix_fds">64</limit> -->
  <!-- <limit name="max_outgoing_bytes">133169152</limit> -->
  <!-- <limit name="max_outgoing_unix_fds">64</limit> -->
  <!-- <limit name="max_message_size">33554432</limit> -->
  <!-- <limit name="max_message_unix_fds">16</limit> -->
  [...]
</busconfig>
```

> What if the Central app left some messages unprocessed and the whole machine goes down - will the unprocessed messages survive? Or is the queue completely in memory?

No, the queue is completely in-memory and will be discarded when either the recipient process or the dbus-daemon process die. D-Bus is a local-machine IPC system, not a MQ framework.